# How do I Install a WiFi driver (RTL8812BU) in Ubuntu 22.04, when the last instruction comes up with 'sudo: ./install-driver.sh: command not found'/

Tags: command-line, drivers

I have followed the instructions from 'How do I install drivers for Realtek RTL8812BU?'

i.e.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y dkms git
mkdir src
cd src
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu.git
cd 88x2bu
sudo ./install-driver.sh
sudo reboot
```

At `sudo ./install-driver.sh` I receive the message `sudo: ./install-driver.sh: command not found`

Here's what I got in 'Terminal'

```
dougie@OptiPlex-780:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Fetched 210 kB in 1s (315 kB/s)       
Reading package lists... Done
dougie@OptiPlex-780:~$ sudo apt-get install -y dkms git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
dkms is already the newest version (2.8.7-2ubuntu2).
git is already the newest version (1:2.34.1-1ubuntu1.4).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 2 not to upgrade.
dougie@OptiPlex-780:~$ mkdir src
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘src’: File exists
dougie@OptiPlex-780:~$ cd src
dougie@OptiPlex-780:~/src$ git clone https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu.git
fatal: destination path '88x2bu' already exists and is not an empty directory.
dougie@OptiPlex-780:~/src$ cd 88x2bu
dougie@OptiPlex-780:~/src/88x2bu$ sudo ./install-driver.sh
sudo: ./install-driver.sh: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong? (... and a heads-up about GitHub requiring both a registration and a 'Personal Access Token' would have been useful!)

Comment: That command only works when your current directory is the one holding the install-driver.sh file.  Change directory to that directory (cd somedirectory ) and repeat the command.

Comment: Being new to this, how do I find out which directory is holding the install-driver.sh file? Perversely, I can navigate to the relevant file from the 'Home' folder in Desktop but if I copy and paste the path into 'Terminal', I'm told that there are too many arguments.

Comment: Don't *describe* the problem. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1419943/edit) to show us actual, complete input and output. Copy it right out of the Terminal and paste it into your question. And keep editing your question in response to comments. Comments are not intended for conversation -- they are intended to help you improve your question until it's understandable and answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [the github page](https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu.git). You are not following [the current instructions](https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702). According to the github page, [the project has moved](https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu#user-content-88x2bu--88x2buko--rocket).

Follow the instructions on [the current project page](https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702). It's basically the same. It appears the only thing that has changed is the location or the git URL for the project.

---

For future reference, it should be noted that the "current instructions" linked in this answer may have changed. Visit [this page](https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu#user-content-88x2bu--88x2buko--rocket) and follow the link to the actual current instructions.

Comment: Also, "too many arguments" when you copy and paste a path is usually due to a space in the path name so you would need to paste the path within "quotation marks".